# dealing with the difference in height between 2 adjoining tiled floors

Tags: tiling

I am having my kichen floor retiled. The kitchen adjoins the hall which is also tiled.  How do I deal with the difference in floor heights.  Not sure if usual threshold strips e.g. between tiles and carpet will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of tapered transitions available. Some install under the tile, like so:

[image]

Obviously the new tile needs to be higher than the old in this case. Another type is the simple beveled marble threshold:

[image]

You could also use a hardwood strip to match your home's woodwork. Your installer should know all this, though, and provide you with options.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the threshold strips for carpet have little teeth to hold the carpet. You will want a flat threshold without teeth. These are available at most home stores.

Comment: or file the teeth off.